# read vendor specific characteristics using bluetoothctl

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez, pybluez

I am able to connect Pair and trust with a BLE device [Sensor Bug 4.0] provided by blueradios.com

I am not able to read Vendor specific characteristics.

I am running bluetoothctl on Debian Linux platform.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What commands so you use to connect and pair?  (If from the command line) What does your code look like?  (If using pybluez)  How do you try to read characteristics? What happens when you try it?

Comment: for connect
>> connect <device id>
for Pair
>> pair <device id>

>>list-attributes
will list all the characterisitics that are SIG approved and non SIG approved [vendor specific]
I can access SIG approved characteristics by select-attribute and read commands.
But for vendor specific, it says authentication required.